# Why do the faces in my model become checkered when rendering?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Could anyone help identify my setup error when rendering using cycles.  The model looks fine in the viewport shading window, but when pushed to the render tool it seems to introduce checkered faces.  This is after I've attached all the texture mapping outputted from substance painter.

[image: Using the render window]

[image: As seen in viewport shader]

Answer (score 1):

My blunder.  Even though duplicated objects were hidden in my layer control, they still showed in the render.  deleted them and issue has been resolved!